# Bootstrap images in content responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the content of the site are some images. It got 400px width. I'm using bootstrap to make my site responsive. When you visit the site from a mobile device the image don't adjust to the `.container`. How to make in-content images responsive with bootstrap?

Comment: Can you add the code or the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap 3.0, add class to image. ie. **img-responsive**
Ref. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images